# How to generate a UUID for each line in a file using AWK or SED?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk, sed

I need to append a UUID ( newly generated unique for each line) to each line of a file. I would prefer to use SED or AWK for this activity and take advantage of UUIDGEN executable on my linux box. I cannot figure out how to generate the the UUID for each line and append it.

I have tried:

```
awk '{print system(uuidgen) $1} myfile.csv
sed -i -- 's/^/$(uuidgen)/g' myfile.csv
```

And many other variations that didn't work. Can this be done with SED or AWK, or should I be investigating another solution that is not shell script based?

Sincerely,
Stephen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just tweaking the syntax on your attempt, something like this should work:

```
awk '("uuidgen" | getline uuid) > 0 {print uuid, $0} {close("uuidgen")}' myfile.csv
```

For example:

```
$ cat file
a
b
c

$ awk '("uuidgen" | getline uuid) > 0 {print uuid, $0} {close("uuidgen")}' file
52a75bc9-e632-4258-bbc6-c944ff51727a a
24c97c41-d0f4-4cc6-b0c9-81b6d89c5b77 b
76de9987-a60f-4e3b-ba5e-ae976ab53c7b c
```

The right solution is to use other shell commands though since the awk isn't buying you anything:

```
$ xargs -n 1 printf "%s %s\n" $(uuidgen) < file
763ed28c-453f-47f4-9b1b-b2f972b2cc7d a
763ed28c-453f-47f4-9b1b-b2f972b2cc7d b
763ed28c-453f-47f4-9b1b-b2f972b2cc7d c
```

Answer (score 5):

Using `bash`, this will create a file outfile.txt with a concatenated uuid:

NOTE: Please run `which bash` to verify the location of your copy of `bash` on your system.  It may not be located in the same location used in the script below.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line
do
    uuid=$(uuidgen)
    echo "$line $uuid" >> outfile.txt
done < myfile.txt
```

myfile.txt:

```
john,doe
mary,jane
albert,ellis
bob,glob
fig,newton
```

outfile.txt

```
john,doe 46fb31a2-6bc5-4303-9783-85844a4a6583
mary,jane a14bb565-eea0-47cd-a999-90f84cc8e1e5
albert,ellis cfab6e8b-00e7-420b-8fe9-f7655801c91c
bob,glob 63a32fd1-3092-4a72-8c24-7b01c400820c
fig,newton 63d38ad9-5553-46a4-9f24-2e19035cc40d
```

Comment: Hello @Cyrus - I would like to comply with your suggestion but I don't see any editing issue(s).  Please advise and thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest to replace both images by text.

Comment: Perhaps a comment as well about the non-standard interpreter location in `#!/usr/local/bin/bash` is due as well. You would be surprised at the number that will copy *verbatim*...

Comment: I tried to change the images to text but it seems its been done already,  No problem.  And I tried to add a note about the `bash` location but presently I cannot edit the answer.  Thanks for all the suggestions and assistance.

Comment: Info on location of `bash` has been added.

Comment: That script will corrupt the output given various inputs. If you're considering writing shell loops to manipulate text then first read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) and at the very least always use `while IFS= read -r line` and always quote your variables `echo "$line $uuid"...` unless you have a specific purpose in mind by not doing so and fully understand the effects/implications. Finally, always use `$(...)`, not the obsolescent `\`...\``.

Comment: @Ed Morton Interesting article you mentioned.  I would prefer to use Perl for this issue but the OP mentions `bash`, `shell` and `linux` in the tags so I went with that approach.  Thank you for your feedback -- I incorporated your suggestions in my answer.

Comment: @Stephen McKain - if you found this answer as useful, as others seemingly have with their upvotes, please mark it as an accepted answer.  Thx

Answer (score 2):

Using `xargs` is simpler here:

```
paste -d " " myfile.csv <(xargs -I {} uuidgen {} < myfile.csv)
```

This will call `uuidgen` for each line of `myfile.csv`

Comment: I suggest this to avoid problems with whitespaces in lines: `xargs -I {} uuidgen {} < myfile.csv | paste -d " " myfile.csv -`

Comment: Whitespaces in myfile.csv create extra lines.

Comment: Oops I didn't realize OP wants to append `uuidgen` output

Comment: Since `uuidgen` ignores all arguments anyway, I would suggest using `xargs -L1` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
awk '{ "uuidgen" |& getline u; print u, $1}' myfile.csv
```

if you want to append instead of prepend change the order of print.

Comment: You don't need the gawk-specific `|&` as it's not a coprocess but you do need to test the result of the call and you do need to close it afterwards. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.

Comment: Yeah. If you don't close then the first returned uuid will be used for every line. awk '{ "uuidgen" | getline u; close("uuidgen"); print u, $1}' myfile.csv

Comment: this solution uses the same UUID for all the rows

Answer (score 0):

You can use `paste` and GNU `sed`:

`paste <(sed 's/.*/uuidgen/e' file) file`

This uses the GNU execute extension `e` to generate a UUID per line, then `paste` pastes the text back together. Use the `-d` `paste` flag to change the delimiter from the default tab, to whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

These all seem pretty slow. Ruby can do it right quick.

```
ruby -r securerandom -ne 'print SecureRandom.uuid + " " + $_' file
```